# Are benchtop lab power supplies usually isolated?

Tags: analog

I want to avoid ground loops in a PCB which has several supplies, but I would like to know in general if benchtop lab power supplies are supposed to be isolated - there is not really much point in measuring that on mines, since I would like to know in general for future projects.

Comment: I tend to assume so but have run into ones that are not which seemed like they would be. Ground loop isn't the biggest problem. Its' shorting somethng out that is.

Comment: Caution! Even when the output is isolated _by design_, that doesn't mean it actually _is_ isolated. I was hooking up an expensive prototype and, to be on the safe side, I  measured voltage between the PSU output and the circuit _before_ connecting them. 25VAC!! _That_ can't be good. Showed it to the engineer in charge,... He thought he would dispel my fears by connecting the green "ground" terminal of the PSU to the black "-" output. The magic smoke made an ugly sound as it escaped. Turns out there was a short between the PSU circuit board and its metal case. No one had ever noticed before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by isolated.

Isolated from input: yes, lab supplies with human-contactable outputs will be galvanically isolated from the input supply (usually AC) via a transformer. This protects from shock hazard.

Isolated from earth: depends, but generally yes for "true" lab supplies (and no for repurposed things like PC ATX supplies). Check the datasheet if in doubt.

[image]

This type of supply has a metal bracket which allows you to earth the negative rail. If you disconnect the bracket, it's floating. You can usually connect these types of supplies in series to create a higher voltage rail (within some limits).

If there is not a discrete earthing terminal like the picture shows above, the best way to know for sure is to measure between earth and the outputs with a DMM.

Answer (score 1):

All lab supplies are floating output.  They would be useless otherwise for many uses. A gnd strap is provided for optional connection to + or -.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
I've asked the same question of this cheap one from CPC about and I expect the answer will be negative.

[image: Cheap PSU]

No separate ground output, and I think I'd measure it myself rather than trust it .